# gulp-jade и вызов функций в файлах *.jade

Tags: gulp, jade

Появился очень интересный вопрос - можно ли вызывать в шаблонах `jade` функции из `gulpfile`?

Например. У нас есть функция `hello(text)`, она просто выводит в консоль значение переданного параметра. Суть в том, чтобы обратиться к этой функции можно было из шаблона.

Приблизительно так:

```
+someBlock

hello('It\'s alive!')

+someBlock
```

Соответственно, когда выполнение таска дойдет до рендеринга jade, в консоли мы увидим `It's alive!`.

Очень важно то, что рендеринг должен осуществляться через плагин **gulp-jade**, а не jade.

Comment: На всякий случай вас уведомлю, что Jade из-за юридических проблем переименовался в Pug. Возможно, вы захотите обновиться :Р

Comment: Про подобный плагин не слышал, но можно свой сделать - находите поиском вхождение нужной ф-ии, вырезаете параметры и выполняете.

Comment: На счет pug - в курсе :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Примерно так:

```
gulp.task('views', function() {
   var languages = ['en', 'ru'];
   i18n.init({
         keyseparator: '::',
         supportedLngs: languages,
         fallbackLng: languages[0],
         detectLngFromPath: 0,
         //forceDetectLngFromPath: true,
         lng: languages[0],
         debug: true
      },
      function() {
         languages.forEach(function(lang) {
            i18n.setLng(lang, function() {
               var
                  testimonialsRaw = fs.readFileSync('./locales/comments/' + lang + '/testimonials.json', 'utf8'),
                  testimonials = JSON.parse(testimonialsRaw),
                  dateNow = new Date(),
                  htmlFilePath = path.join(__dirname + '/public/index_' + lang + '.html'),

                  // Render Pug to HTML
                  templateHtml = pug.renderFile('./views/index.pug', {
                     testimonials: testimonials,
                     currentYear: dateNow.getFullYear(),
                     t: i18n.t,
                     i18n: i18n
                  });
               fs.writeFileSync(htmlFilePath, templateHtml);
            });
         });
      });
});
```